# typedef enum explanation in c

Tags: c, typedef

I'm looking at a header file for an ADC on a micro controller and the following code is in it.

```
/**
 * ADC channels type.
*/

typedef enum {
    ADC_CH_0,
    ADC_CH_1,
    ADC_CH_2,
    ADC_CH_3,
    ADC_CH_4,
    ADC_CH_5,
    ADC_CH_6, 
} adc_channel_t;
```

And in the main.c for the ADC there is the following line of code

```
adc_channel_t channels[] = {ADC_CH_4, ADC_CH_5};
```

I was wondering why would you need declare new data types for the ADC? and what does typedef enum mean?

Thanks

Comment: `typedef` is just used to name an abbreviation for a type, so you don't have to retype the whole thing every time you use it.

Comment: There's nothing special about using it to abbreviate an `enum` type.

Comment: It's not necessarily that you're creating a new data type for the ADC. An enum is an int which you can use as an identifier for a group of constants. From a readability standpoint it becomes clear later in code that `ADC_CH_0` (which has a value of 0) is exactly channel 0. Simply using integers for said group is a disaster waiting to happen. Enums help keep things clean.

Answer (score 17):

As a complement to the answer by artm the `typedef` is added in front of the `enum`, to ease the use of the `enum`. Had the declaration looked like this instead:

```
enum adc_channel_t {
    ADC_CH_0,
    ADC_CH_1,
    ADC_CH_2,
    ADC_CH_3,
    ADC_CH_4,
    ADC_CH_5,
    ADC_CH_6, 
};
```

Then the line `adc_channel_t channels[] = {ADC_CH_4, ADC_CH_5};` would have to be written as:

```
enum adc_channel_t channels[] = {ADC_CH_4, ADC_CH_5};
```

The `typedef` allows us to ignore the `enum` at every use of the type.

Using useful constants is often preferred over "magic numbers", though it might seem a bit strange in this case the constants give little extra information. It can however be useful since the enumerator serves as extra description. For instance your IDE which will expect a value of type `adc_channel_t` will be able to suggest the channels: `ADC_CH_0` through `ADC_CH_6` that might be the valid range of values, instead of simply telling you to use a number.

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple components to why this is done.

1. What does typedef do
2. Why typedef the enum

A `typedef` allows you to define new types. This allows you to make your intent more clear.

```
 char id; // but my id is a number!
 typedef unsigned char uint8; // ok now we can use uint8 instead of char
 uint8 id; // better! Now we know we should only interpret id as a number.
```

Second in C you need to alway specify `enum` and `struct` when referring to those:

```
enum CarModels_e {
    Bravia,
    Uno
};


enum CarModels_e the_model;
enum CarModels_e other_model
// this gets boring fast...
```

So programmers (who are lazy) will try to avoid typing too much. For that they create a new type:

```
typedef enum CarModels_e CarModels; // now we don't need to type enum every time!

CarModels the_model;
CarModels other_model
// Less typing! Happier programmer!
```

But still you have to type twice `enum CarModels_e` so they combine that too in one declaration:

```
typedef enum /* Don't even need a name here anymore! Much less typing :) */ {
    Bravia,
    Uno
} CarModels;
```

---

Why use an `enum` instead of number directly? Because this way you can give meaning to numbers. So next time they (or anyone else) reads their code they still know what those numbers are all about.

```
// Example
if (measured_frequency == 12345) { // hmm where does this come from?

if (measured_frequency == MaximumMotorFrequency) { // Ah! Now i'll know what this is about in ten years!
```

Comment: To be pedantic, if you really want to make your intent more clear, your `typedef char uint8;` should be either `typedef unsigned char uint8;` or `typedef char int8;`, as the `u` usually implies that the type is unsigned ;).

Comment: @NiBZ You are right that an explicit `unsigned`/`signed` avoids ambiguity. However, the standard defines the "signness" of `char` as implementation-defined. Therefore, `typedef char int8;` is as wrong as `typedef char uint8;`.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering why would you need declare new data types for the ADC? and what does typedef enum mean?

`typedef enum` is a way to group related constants. You can instead declared seven `const` from `ADC_CH_0` to `ADC_CH_6`, but because they are all related, it's better to use `enum` here (with each `enum` constant is by default increased by 1).

You can later use type `adc_channel_t` to declare variables, with the range is guaranteed to be within the declared enum constants.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way to do this is as follows:

```
typedef enum powerState_tag {
    PS_OFF,
    PS_ON
} powerState_te;
```

This does several things in one expression.

1. Declares the enum pwerState_tag {PS_OFF, PS_ON}.
2. Creates a typedef of powerState_te.

I usually add the pwerState_tag for the purpose of some code parsers/editors will display the enum as unnamed. I add the suffixes to indicate the _tag is the name of the enum and _te is a typed enum. I duplicate the name in both the _tag and _te for symmetry. Those are not standardized naming conventions and can be named anything you'd like unless your coding standard states otherwise. The Barr Group has an online standard that I've seen referenced at several jobs and is pretty good. They don't use the _te to identify what type of typedef it is though.

The biggest benefit of type defining enumerations in this way is that if someone passes in a value that is not defined, the compiler will let you know at compile time.

For example the following would cause a compile time error in your example above:

```
adc_channel_t channels[] = {99, -1};
```

But the following would not fail because 4 and 5 are included in the enumeration:

```
adc_channel_t channels[] = {4, 5};
```

Some editors use the typedef enum to auto fill as well.

```
adc_channel_t channel;
// when you begin to assign the value, the editor will offer suggestions
channel = AD \\<auto completes up to _> and you have to merely type the number of click the value you like.
```

Most code I've worked in that did not use the typedef enum pattern would pass in a generic int without specifying that it was the enumeration and utilize ADC_CH_4 like that of a #define.

```
uint8_t getAdcVal(uint8_t channel); // A
uint8_t getAdcVal(adc_channel_t channel); //B
```

While A functions properly when the user uses a valid range, the compiler does not validate it is within the range of the enumeration at compile time like it would for B.

[Barr Group's coding standard](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/Books/Embedded-C-Coding-Standard/Data-Type-Rules/Naming-Conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand `typedef` and `enum` individually.

> **enum**

It is a user defined data type which is used to assign names to
integral constants. It's like `#define`, but there is difference between
them and we will discuss that in later part of the answer.

Consider this example code:

```
enum bool{
FALSE, 
TRUE
};
```

What is happening over here is we are defining a data type of type bool and it has two names - FALSE and TRUE. The compiler initializes the values of these constants and the next name's value is incremented by 1 with regard to previous value. In our case, the value of FALSE will be 0, TRUE will be 1. If we assign the value of FALSE as say 6, the value of TRUE (which comes after FALSE) will be FALSE++, i.e., 7. We can initialize the value on our own and both or all the names in the data structure can have same values.
The question arises is Why use enum when we have `#define`? The answer is because:

1. enum is local to the scope
2. The compiler initializes the values
   NOTE: All the names must be UNIQUE in the scope and only integral
   constants are allowed as values to the names.

> **typedef**

Consider our example where we have defined the data type and now we want to use it in our code. The way you can use it is:

```
enum bool var; //declared a variable var of type enum bool
var  = FALSE;
```

The issue with such declaration is you have to type `enum bool` before the variable of that type every time you want to declare. So what we do is we give the data type (enum bool) a nickname or an alias and whenever we want to use it in our code, we can declare a variable of the type the nickname given to the data type. The `typedef` keyword is used to give a nickname to the datatype. Example:

```
typedef enum bool{
FALSE,
TRUE
} BoolTypedef_t;
```

So whenever we want to use any member from this data type we can just use it like this:

```
BoolTypedef_t var; 
var = TRUE; 
printf("%d", var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this example, you can better understand when using typedef and when it is unnecessary.

file `enums.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum
{
  MONDAY = 1,
  TUESDAY,
  WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY,
  FRIDAY,
  SATURDAY,
  SUNDAY,
} day_t;

typedef enum
{
  CAPITAL = 0x00000001, // or = 1
  UPPER = 0x00000010,   // or = 2
  LOWER = 0x00000100,   // or = 4
} day_format_t;

void get_day_name(char *, day_t, day_format_t);
void to_upper(char *);
void to_lower(char *);

int main(void)
{

  day_t day = MONDAY;
  while (day <= SUNDAY)
  {
    char name[20];
    if (day == SATURDAY || day == SUNDAY)
    {
      get_day_name(name, day, UPPER);
    }
    else
    {
      get_day_name(name, day, CAPITAL);
    }

    printf("'%s', is the name for day of the week: %d\n", name, day);
    day++;
  }

  return 0;
}

void get_day_name(char *src, day_t day, day_format_t format)
{

  char name[10];
  switch (day)
  {
  case MONDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Monday");
    break;
  case TUESDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Tuesday");
    break;
  case WEDNESDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Wednesday");
    break;
  case THURSDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Thursday");
    break;
  case FRIDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Friday");
    break;
  case SATURDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Saturday");
    break;
  case SUNDAY:
    strcpy(name, "Sunday");
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }

  switch (format)
  {
  case CAPITAL:
    strcpy(src, name);
    break;
  case UPPER:
  {
    to_upper(name);
    strcpy(src, name);
    break;
  }
  case LOWER:
    to_lower(name);
    strcpy(src, name);
    break;

  default:
    strcpy(src, name);
    break;
  }
}

void to_upper(char *name)
{

  while (*name != '\0')
  {
    *name = toupper(*name);
    name++;
  }
}

void to_lower(char *name)
{
  while (*name != '\0')
  {
    *name = tolower(*name);
    name++;
  }
}
```

to test:

```bash
gcc enums.c -o enums && chmod +x enums && ./enums
```

result:

```bash
'Monday', is the name for day of the week: 1
'Tuesday', is the name for day of the week: 2
'Wednesday', is the name for day of the week: 3
'Thursday', is the name for day of the week: 4
'Friday', is the name for day of the week: 5
'SATURDAY', is the name for day of the week: 6
'SUNDAY', is the name for day of the week: 7
```